# PiFM using microphone

Tags: raspbian

http://youtu.be/CBb8BN0dqoQ

according to this video where and how do i connect microphone?
i want to broadcast a microphone talking and music with a mixer

Answer (score 0):

It reads from a wav file, not from a microphone.

Taken from main.c:

```
Usage: program wavfile.wav [freq] [sample rate] [stereo]

Where wavfile is 16 bit 22.5kHz Stereo. Set wavfile to '-' to use stdin.
freq is in Mhz (default 103.3)
sample rate of wav file in Hz

Play an empty file to transmit silence
```

You may want to use traditional mic, analogue sources and mixer. Then feed small transmitter which expect signals coming from earphone plug of android phone/mp3 player, etc.

[example](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/metra-fm-stereo-modulator/9848376.p;jsessionid=474BF0147BDFB018EBBF937B9EC3390D.bbolsp-app01-127?id=1218183122368&skuId=9848376&st=categoryid$abcat0208031&cp=1&lp=11)

Comment: got something to try  **arecord ­fS16_LE ­r 22050 ­Dplughw:1,0 ­ | sudo ./pifm ­ 100.1 22050** waiting to my USB sound card to arrive